# artisan serve fails after update to laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.3

After an upgrade from laravel 5.2 to 5.3 every php artisan "action" fails.
(e.g. php artisan serve)

```
[ErrorException] 
Declaration of App\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated
($request, App\Exceptions\AuthenticationException $exception) 
should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler::unauthenticated
($request,Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException $e)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you've properly updated the `App\Exceptions\Handler` and in general any "boilerplate" type classes you're using.